# Refresh DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a dataGridView bound to a table. On the same form as the DataGridView I have a few textboxes and a button to add new values to the database and want them displayed in the gridView too. Saving in the database works, just the new values are not shown in the gridView. I have tried the following:

```
this.Validate();
this.pBindingSource.EndEdit();
this.pTableAdapter.Update(this.DBDataSet);
pDataGridView.Refresh();
```

This didn't work. From my understanding the .Refresh method only redraws the GridView, so it should work after updating the tableAdapter, so I thought. But it doesn't.

Then I've tried:

```
this.pDataGridView.DataSource = null;
this.pDataGridView.DataSource = this.pBindingSource;
pDataGridView.Refresh();
```

which doesn't work either. Then tried to ResetBindings() for the binding source, which didn't work, and then I ran out of ideas.

How to refresh the DataGridView?

Comment: I think you need to use: this.pBindingSource.DataSource

Comment: It didn't work. Thanks for the imput tho

Comment: First question: Silvelight or WPF?
Second one: What type You use for data collection - pBindingSource?

Comment: 1.C sharp as per title buddy.                  2. private System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource pBindingSource

Comment: is it a windows-form application? or another type?

Comment: @Meonester Windows Forms supports data binding. I don't think he even knows what Silverlight and WPF are.

Comment: how did you overcome your issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can modify like

```
this.pDataGridView.DataSource = null;
this.pDataGridView.DataBind();
this.pDataGridView.DataSource = this.pBindingSource;
pDataGridView.DataBind();
```

Comment: There is no .DataBind() method for pDataGridView. I'm using Visual Studio 2010 btw

Comment: @orzacsergiu, just so you know: the version of VS has absolutely nothing to do with the features of c#. I think you should state your version of .Net framework.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this:

```
this.[tablename]tableAdapter.Fill(this.[Database]DataSet.[tablename]);
```

in every button command , it worked for me at least.

For instance my code looks like this:

```
this.studentinfoTableAdapter.Fill(this.studentDataSet.studentinfo);
```